# Check Office365 session

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

Is there any solutions to understand from my MVC application that user already signed in into Office365?

Currently I'm using the code below to authenticate to my MVC application:

`var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/MyTenantId");

var authResult = authContext.AcquireToken("https://MyTenantId/AppWebApi",
                    "ClientId", new Uri("redirect uri"));`

By this code user is suggested to enter his credentials to sign in into Azure Active Directory. And it works fine, but it doesn't see that user already signed in to Office365 and work with Word, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote there does not work in a web application. It might work while you are hitting localhost, but as soon as you deploy your web app to an actual server it will not be able to pop out the dialog. Did you get that code form some sample? Could you point me to that? This is already the 2nd question containing the same error in 2 days, after 2 or 3 years of the library being available.

Back to your question.

How did the user sign in your application? If you would have used AAD to handle web sign on, like in [this sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet), you would know upfront (and the answer would be always 'yes', just for the fact that he/she'd need to in order to have access to your application).
If you are using a different sign on system, there are techniques for finding out if a user is signed in without showing any UX, but they are pretty advanced (requiring the use of a hidden frame and special request parameters) and before digging deeper in that I think it would be useful to know what your scenario requires. Do you need a token, or do you simply need to know if the user is already signed in in O365?

Comment: 1st part: I'll try to find where I find example to use this code.

Comment: 2nd part: I just need to know if the user is already signed in in O365. If not - I need to show Sign In form.

Comment: I've find example of code in this link (look Figure 7): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx

Comment: Sample you've linked above is perfect for me! Thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks for the link! The article demonstrates how to work with a native client, which has a very different architecture than a web application. I am glad that the sample linked above helped!